With TComPort, is there a way to repeat readline until buffer is empty?
Using TComPort with Delphi I need to read one line at the time, until the input buffer is empty. My problem is that the ReadLine procedure is triggered by the RxChar event, resulting in that only the first line (all are terminated with #13) is read. The remaining lines stay in the buffer until again a RxChar event is caused (by the remote writing to the UART port), triggering a new ReadLine. This means lines are usually delayed (while sitting in the buffer) for quite a long time. I need the transfer to be close to real-time.
In other language environment I have used While in_waiting, but cannot find this with TComPort. How can I do 'while something in the input buffer do readline'?

Please edit your post to include all relevant parts of your code, that handles the received characters. I assume RxChar is triggered for every recerived character, no? Also, explain in detail why there would be lines (plural) in the buffer for quite a long time.

I use TComport a lot to read Barcodes . I am not sure if you are using TComport correctly . What I do is :
On Start I initialize the Comport :
  ComLineScanner.Port:='COM1';
  ComLineScanner.BaudRate:=br9600;
  ComLineScanner.DataBits:=dbEight;
  ComLineScanner.StopBits:=sbOneStopBit;
  ComLineScanner.Parity.Bits:=prNone;
  ComLineScanner.FlowControl.FlowControl:=fcNone;

Then I simply listen non-stop for new data :
procedure TMain.ComLineScannerRxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var
  Str: String;
  Data : String;
begin
  ComLineScanner.ReadStr(Str, Count);
  RawData:=RawData+Str;

  // only process the string if we have recieved the END Signal
  if Pos('[E]',RawData) <> 0 then
  begin

  end
  else
  begin
    if Assigned(Debug) then
      Debug.memDebug.Lines.Add('[ '+DateTimeToStr(now)+' ] [ NOT ACCEPTED ] '+RawData);
  end;

end;

RawData is a Private Global Variable .
This works for me pretty well in a real time production environment 24/7 .

Maybe you are using a different TComPort, the one that I have purchased from Winsoft does not have the ReadStr(string, count) procedure.

Include the vendor information in your q, this will help others trying to help you
